# Typescript anonymous class

Tags: typescript

Is there a way in typescript to create anonymous class?

my code:

```
export abstract class Runnable {
    public abstract run();
}
```

and I'm trying to do something like this:

```
new Runnable {
    runner() {
        //implement
    }
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: @JaredSmith atrocities XD

Comment: Not so atrocity. If you want a callback with many different functions, what do you prefer? A) Send as many parameters to the function as the callback methods, or B) Encapsulate all the callbacks methods in a single software unit that gives it cohesion?

Comment: If you want a short way you can do:

```const myRunnable = <Runnable>{ run:() => { console.log("I ran"); } }```

But I think this is more like typecasting, not inheritance

Answer (score 94):

Yes, here is the way.

The abstract class:

```
export abstract class Runnable {
  public abstract run();
}
```

An anonymous implementation:

```
const runnable = new class extends Runnable {
  run() {
    // implement here
  }
}();
```

Comment: I had voted for this answer because this is the most compact form and truly assigns an anonymous class (without defining another named class).

Answer (score 26):

Not quite, but you can do this:

```
abstract class Runnable {
    public abstract run();
}

let runnable = new (class MyRunnable extends Runnable {
    run() {
        console.log("running...");
    }
})();

runnable.run(); // running...
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20Runnable%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20abstract%20run()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20runnable%20%3D%20new%20(class%20MyRunnable%20extends%20Runnable%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20run()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22running...%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Arunnable.run()%3B%20%2F%2F%20running...))

The problem with this approach however is that the interpreter will evaluate the class every time it uses it, unlike with a compiled language (such as java) in which the compiler only evaluates it once.

Comment: Actually, just `new class extends Runnable { /* bla bla bla */ }` seems to work.

Answer (score 9):

### How to create Anonymous Class?

Let's say you have a interface `Runnable` and an abstract class `Task`.when you declare a class `Foo` in typescript you actual create an class instance of `Foo` & a constructor function for the class `Foo`.you could want to see depth in [typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#advanced-techniques).Anonymous class that ref as a constructor function like `{new(...args):type}` that can be created using `new` keyword.

```
interface Runnable {
    run(): void;
}

abstract class Task {
    constructor(readonly name: string) {
    }

    abstract run(): void;
}
```

#### Create anonymous class extends superclass via `class extends ?`

```
test('anonymous class extends superclass by `class extends ?`', () => {
    let stub = jest.fn();
    let AntTask: {new(name: string): Task} = class extends Task {
        //anonymous class auto inherit its superclass constructor if you don't declare a constructor here.
        run() {
            stub();
        }
    };

    let antTask: Task = new AntTask("ant");
    antTask.run();

    expect(stub).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(antTask instanceof Task).toBe(true);
    expect(antTask.name).toBe("ant");
});
```

### create anonymous class implements interface/type via `class ?`.

```
test('anonymous class implements interface by `class ?`', () => {
    let stub = jest.fn();
    let TestRunner: {new(): Runnable} = class {
        run = stub
    };

    let runner: Runnable = new TestRunner();
    runner.run();

    expect(stub).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I think you don't need `: {new(name: string): Task}` in your second example.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create an inline local class and immediately extend it.

```js
interface Runnable {
    run();
}

// ...

const runnable = new (class ___Runnable implements Runnable {
    run() { /*...*/ }
});

/* parentheses are optional */

return new class ___Runnable implements Runnable {
    run() { /*...*/ }
}

/* do not worry, ___Runnable does not leak in to scope.
its scope is the hidden (extra) parentheses. */
```