# In Typescript, how to access members outside a "anonymous" class

Tags: typescript

I created a "anaonymous" class based on this: [Typescript anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766986/typescript-anonymous-class)

But I don't know how to access the outer scope members. Here is an example code:

```
class BaseCounter {
  counter = 1;

  count() {
    console.log(++this.counter);
  }

  getDoubleCounter() {
    return new class DoubleCounter extends BaseCounter {
        count() {
            // In Java, we can access the outer scope counter by ClassName.this like this
            // BaseCounter.this.counter += 2
            // console.log(BaseCounter.this.counter); 
        }
    }();

}
```

Comment: Classes in JS (and same in TS) are just constructor functions that return a new object, and fields exist on the instance level. So even if you return an anonymous class from another class it still constructs a new object. Since your anonymous class extends BaseCounter it has `counter` field and you can increase it by `this.counter +=2`.

Comment: Does [this](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDCB7ArgOwC4IE7QG8AoaU6YdbPaAXmgEYBuIksizLACgEpDWy2KDBBQgEAOhAoA5pwDUcrAAsAlhHHsqubswEBfFgOkIsAEXQAjMag54efAQIrCs0C4htaAKqph1larqOpLgmaLgY0BgIAO7k4FDQ5mhWyJQ4+AgAHjgYACYw8BBptvjEwcGaXLzlFXXuxZ4ZPmoa6dRydABMQXWVQiJikjKcDSXevm2lOvx9BnV6PL3QBgbOEK4WwPS0UbFwHu24S0Trrnnbu1v04sZmltZHJ2fQF11X27cmyalNdjMvLbvOjROJFcYZE7XKbYJbQAD08OgXSI0KqcMR0AAzEQLjd0ToEUiAKy44BdGHVRhE6AAdlR5MpGKRKLR6WZ0AAHGSKQTqZj6AAGBm89mEzE4lhSohAA) meet your needs?  If so I'll write it up as an answer

Comment: Thanks jaclz for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

Actually I can assign parent this to an variable like this

```
class BaseCounter {
  counter = 1;

  count() {
    console.log(++this.counter);
  }

  getDoubleCounter() {
    const parentThis = this;
    return new class DoubleCounter extends BaseCounter {
        count() {
            parentThis.counter += 2
            console.log(parentThis.counter); 
        }
    }();

}
```

Comment: Indeed this is the way you should do it in TS